# To remove "Grand Total (Excl.Tax)" from Invoice email Magento 2

Tags: magento2, email-templates, invoice, sales, order-email

I want to remove this line from my invoice email.
"Grand Total (Excl.Tax)"

[image]

can anyone please tell me the file name or the process to remove this line from invoice email.

thank you

Comment: Can you please show me pdf please

Comment: updated my question with screenshot, see above

Answer (score 2):

Copy this file from **vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/order/totals.phtml** and add in your theme:  **/app/design/frontend/Nameplace/Themename/Magento_Sales/templates/order/totals.phtml**

```
<?php foreach ($block->getTotals() as $_code => $_total): ?>
    <?php if ($_total->getBlockName()): ?>
        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml($_total->getBlockName(), false); ?>
    <?php else:?>
    <tr class="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_code?>">
        <th <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getLabelProperties()?> scope="row">
            <?php if ($_total->getStrong()):?>  
        <?php
        if ($_total->getLabel() == "Grand Total (Excl.Tax)") {
            continue;
        }
        ?>
            <strong><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_total->getLabel());?></strong>
            <?php else:?>
            <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_total->getLabel());?>
            <?php endif?>
        </th>
        <td <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getValueProperties()?> data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_total->getLabel());?>">
            <?php if ($_total->getStrong()):?>
            <strong><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->formatValue($_total) ?></strong>
            <?php else:?>
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->formatValue($_total) ?>
            <?php endif?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endif?>
<?php endforeach?>
```

Comment: yes, I did the same before, and it works for me. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: The correct file path for me is Magento_Sales/templates/email/totals.phtml. Better to add if ($_code=="tax"){ continue;} right after foreach so you do not add extra tr in.